# Systemd service not restarting after VM reboot

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl

I have a `systemd` service with the following unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom service 
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my-script
Restart=always
Environment=FOO=BAR
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/my-service/out.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/my-service/err.log
```

However after a VM reboot it does not restart.

When I try to enable it I get the following

```
sudo systemctl enable my-service.service
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

What options among the above should I choose for the unit file?

I just want my service to start after each reboot.

Comment: you are missing the section : `[Install] \n
WantedBy=multi-user.target
` or something similar